# 403 on localhost after adding symlink

Tags: permissions, apache2, symbolic-link

I deleted the folder `/var/www` and created symlink like this:

```
ln -s /home/user/Dropbox/dev/www/ /var/www
```

here it is

```
ls -l /var
lrwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   32 мар 29 18:34 www -> /home/user/Dropbox/dev/www/
```

and

```
ls -l /home/user/Dropbox/dev/
drwxrwx--- 14 user user 4096 мар 29 18:55 www
```

after that I added `www-data` to group `user`

documentroot for localhost is `/var/www/html` (`/home/user/Dropbox/dev/www/html` exists)

and now when I go to localhost I see Forbidden.

Comment: Is `/home/user/Dropbox/dev/www/html` owned by group `user`?

Comment: have you logged out and back in yet? sometimes you have to before the  new groups take effect

Comment: Do you have `Options FollowSymlinks` in the appropriate context of your Apache configuration? It is the default value but can be overriden. You should also read your Apache logfiles they will explain why the 403 error code.

Comment: The logout/login process @John refers to means _restarting apache_ in this case (`systemctl restart apache2.service`).

Comment: actually its logging out of ubuntu and logging back in to refresh the group permissions .. not sure restarting apache will reinitialize the groups with the added permissions but logging out of the users account and logging back in (or rebooting) will for sure

Comment: Include the output of `namei -l /home/user/Dropbox/www`, please. (Replace `user` with the actual username when running the command)  I'll bet this is a permissions issue.

Comment: yes, /home/user/Dropbox/dev/www/html owned by user

Comment: Yes, Options FollowSylinks is in VH-config

Comment: login/logout, apache restart/reload gives no result

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in permissions of Dropbox folder

```
chmod -R 775 Dropbox
```

works for me